# get back to the first step in multistep minimal form after settimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, settimeout

I'm using copdrops `stepsForm.js` and I modified it in some way. Everything is fine, but as I'm not familiar that much with javascript I couldn't make it back to the first step (first question) after the form has been submitted.

this is the codrops script:

https://github.com/codrops/MinimalForm

and this is the modification I made to reset the form and get back to the first question(step) after being submitted.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgdQgg

and this is the modified javascript I used and also has been added to the end of codepen's javascript:

```
var theForm = document.getElementById( 'theForm' );

new stepsForm( theForm, {
    onSubmit : function( form ) {
        // hide form
        classie.addClass( theForm.querySelector( '.simform-inner' ), 'hide' );
        var messageEl = theForm.querySelector( '.final-message' );
        messageEl.innerHTML = 'Thank you! We\'ll be in touch.';
        classie.addClass( messageEl, 'show' );

        setTimeout(function(){
                form.reset()
            }, 2500);
        setTimeout(function(){
            classie.removeClass( messageEl, 'show' )
        }, 3000);
        setTimeout(function(){
            classie.removeClass( theForm.querySelector( '.simform-inner' ), 'hide' )
        }, 3500);
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSBIN DEMO](http://jsbin.com/hupateviza/1/edit?html,js,output)

```
// submits the form
    stepsForm.prototype._submit = function() {
        this.options.onSubmit( this.el );
        // Once the form is submitted, let's reset
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            self.current = 0;
            self.isFilled = false;
            self._init();
            self._progress();
        }, 3500);
    }
```

At the end of `setTimeout`, place

```
setTimeout(function(){
    classie.removeClass( theForm.querySelector( '.simform-inner' ), 'hide' );
    $("ol.questions li").removeClass("current");
}, 3500);
```

Comment: there is a problem with the edited code. When the form submits for the first time, the next time, the error message is being showed continuously even before checking the input value!!! didn't you notice it?!

Answer (score 2):

Afshin is right. There is a problem of validation being thrown up even before entering any value on second turn. After debugging I found the reason was because of the `self._init();` being called in `onSubmit()` function which in turn calls `bindEvents()`. This causes duplicate event binding and hence when we move along the form the this.current is increased twice. To resolve this a new function (e.g `_reinit()`) should be created which is same as `_init()` except the `bindEvents()` function call being removed `in _reinit()`.